# AAD v2.0: unable to use .default scope with device code flow

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'm wondering if anyone has run into this problem. I'm trying to authenticate to OneDrive using AAD v2.0, and the device code flow. My app has the following permissions configured in the Azure portal:

- Microsoft Graph:

  - email
  - Files.ReadWrite.All
  - offline_access
  - openid
  - profile
  - User.Read

Each time I try to authenticate, I get the following error message from the token endpoint:

> AADSTS70011: The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. One or more scopes in 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default openid offline_access' are not compatible with each other.

However, when I use the usual authorization code flow, it works. Similarly, if I use the scope `https://graph.microsoft.com/Files.ReadWrite.All openid offline_access` instead of `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default openid offline_access`, it also works.

Is there something about the `.default` scope that is incompatible with the device code flow?

---

More info:

The app can be used by "Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)". I'm authenticating to the "consumers" tenant because I want to access my personal OneDrive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `openid offline_access` from the `scope`, it should be `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`, when you use `/.default`, they are not needed,  all permissions registered by the application will be included.

Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#the-default-scope

[image]

**Update:**

I can reproduce your issue with `/consumers` and a personal account in the auth url, if I modify it to `/<tenant-id>`, it works fine, you could refer to the steps below.

1.In the postman, use the request below.

Request URL:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/oauth2/v2.0/devicecode
```

Request Body:

```
client_id=<client-id>
scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

[image]

2.In the browser, navigate to the `https://microsoft.com/devicelogin`, input the code and login your user account, the app will let you consent the permission, click the `Accept`.

[image]

3.After login successfully, in the postman, use the request below.

Request URL:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

Request Body:

```
grant_type: urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:device_code
client_id: <client-id>
device_code: <device_code in the screenshot of step 1>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Would you know why it works with the authorization code flow, though? Is this a bug with auth code?

Comment: @HongOoi Maybe, I never tried that, it's a wrong usage, even in the auth code flow.

Comment: Actually, I just tried the devicecode flow with just the .default scope (no openid offline_access) and it still failed

Comment: I do have "allow public client flows" enabled in the app authentication pane, so device code should work, and it does work if I don't use .default

Comment: @HongOoi What's the error when you using `/.default`?

Comment: Same: "AADSTS70011: The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. One or more scopes in 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default' are not compatible with each other."

Comment: @HongOoi Well, let me have a test and update for you.

Comment: @HongOoi I can reproduce your issue with `/consumers`, looks you need to use `/<tenant-id>` even if you are using a personal account, see my update.

Comment: You're right, I can authenticate to my own tenant but not "consumers". Looks like a special restriction for that tenant only. Do you know if this is intended?

Comment: Still, it authenticates with an explicit scope so problem solved, at least

Comment: @HongOoi It's weird, from this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-device-code#device-authorization-request), it says `It can also be the directory tenant that you want to request permission from in GUID or friendly name format`, but from [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols#endpoints), it says if we use tenant id, it just `Allows only users with work/school accounts from a particular Azure AD tenant to sign into the application.`